# Responsive grid for Onsen UI

Tags: cordova, responsive-design, hybrid-mobile-app, onsen-ui, monaca

Unfortunately Onsen UI does not have a responsive grid for placing blocks on screens of various sizes. What grids can you recommend for use with Onsen UI? I have experience with Bootstrap but this library is too big to use it in a project for a responsive grid only. I’ve explored some other grids, but unlike Bootstrap, they can not hide some blocks on small screens or change their order (just make a stack instead of a line). Does anyone have a positive experience with a responsive grid for Onsen UI?

Answer (score 1):

[Skeleton](http://getskeleton.com) is a well established very lightweight grid which might fit your needs.

Out of the box their grid system collapses to a single column on mobile, it has a limited number of helper classes and [I found this source](https://gist.github.com/tommoor/8550820) which lists plenty of push and pull mixins if you need more control over ordering of your columns. You could probably pick and choose just the one's you need. eg

```
/* Push & Pull */
    .container .push-by-one                   { left: 60px;  }
```

I started a codepen based on some code from the Skeleton site which you can play with: https://codepen.io/panchroma/pen/JNXoVP

**Update**

> if I have 3 colums I can't create this screen layout: large screen:
>   column1 5/12, column2 5/12, column3 2/12; medium screen: column1 7/12,
>   column2 5/12, column3 hidden; small screen: column1 100%, column2 100%
>   on the next line, column3 hidden. I'm right?

This is no problem with some media queries and a little custom CSS. If you check out [my updated codepen](https://codepen.io/panchroma/pen/JNXoVP) you'll see that I'm hidding col 3 with `display:none;` and `display:block;` at different viewports.

To change the width of column 1 I inpspected the Skeleton CSS and have used its rule for 7/12 grid to overide the width for the 5/12 grid

**HTML**

Skeleton: Responsive CSS Boilerplate

```
</head>
<body>

  <!-- Primary Page Layout
  –––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– -->

    <div class="container">

  <!-- columns should be the immediate child of a .row -->
  <div class="row">
    <div class="five columns overide"><h5>Column 1</h5>5/12 large screen, 7/12 med screen, 100% small</div>
    <div class="five columns"><h5>Column 2</h5>5/12 large & medium screens, 100% small</div>
    <div class="two columns hidden-md"><h5>Column 3</h5>2/12 large screen, hidden medium and small screens</div>

  </div>
</div> <!-- end container-->



<!-- End Document
  –––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– -->
</body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
/* Mobile first queries */
 .hidden-md{
   display:none;
 }

/* Larger than mobile */
@media (min-width: 400px) {}

/* Larger than phablet */
@media (min-width: 550px) {}

/* Larger than tablet */
@media (min-width: 750px) {}

/* Larger than desktop */
@media (min-width: 1000px) {}

/* Larger than Desktop HD */
@media (min-width: 1200px) {}


/* Custom helper class */

@media (min-width: 750px) {
  .hidden-md{
      display:block;
    }
}

/* Custom Grid Width */
@media (min-width: 550px) and (max-width: 749px) {
  .five.columns.overide{
     width: 56.6666666667%; 
  }

}
```

**Another Update**

> My dream - to find lightweight CSS grid with Bootstrap functionality
>   :)

For min file size it might be hard to match Skeleton + some hand-rolled CSS.

One other option I can think of though is create a regular Bootstrap site then run it through UnCSS.

I've done this a handful of times with Bootstrap based sites. I had mixed success on dynamic CMS sites, really good results on less complex static sites and got an 80-90% reduction in the CSS file size.

There are a number of ways to use UnCSS. I used this [Github code](https://github.com/giakki/uncss) with Grunt and Node. I see there's also [an online resource](https://uncss-online.com).

Good luck in your hunt!

Comment: Thanks for answer! But as I see - it is impossible with Skeleton to change width or hide some columns for small screens?
I.e. if I have 3 colums I can't create this screen layout:
large screen: column1 5/12, column2 5/12, column3 2/12; 
medium screen: column1 7/12, column2 5/12, column3 hidden; 
small screen: column1 100%, column2 100% on the next line, column3 hidden. 

I'm right?

Comment: Hi @David , thanks for update! Yes I know that we can use CSS for these tricks. But Bootstrap grid have predefined classes for these cases (for example: `hidden-xs` for hide column on extrasmall screens, `col-lg-5` and `col-md-7` for define different width on the large and medium screens  etc.). My dream - to find lightweight CSS grid with Bootstrap functionality :)